# Redirect to login page if localstorage not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

The aim is if the user logout or `localStorage` is not found it should automatically redirect to login page and it will logout all opened tabs in the same browser. If the user presses logout button, it will redirect to the login page or else if the user manually clears browsing history(that time `localStorage` seems empty) it will automatically redirect to login page. The following code did not work when opened with single tab and if he deletes browser history(`localStorage` empty). Any suggesstions?

```
function signOutAllTab() {
    var allTabLogOut = 'allTabLogOut';
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(allTabLogOut, allTabLogOut);
        //localStorage.removeItem(allTabLogOut);
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('storage', function (event) {
    if (event.key == 'logout-event') {
        window.location = 'signin?logoutAllTabs=yes';
    }
}, false);

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (signOutAllTab() && signOutTabs) {
        $('#allSignOut').on('click', function () {
            localStorage.setItem('logout-event', 'logout');
            return true;
        });
        setInterval(function () {
            if (!localStorage.getItem("allTabLogOut"))
                localStorage.setItem('logout-event', 'logout' + Math.random());
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Regards,

Sasi

Answer (score 0):

Single tab not work is because that When a page of a homologous page modifies localstorage, the remaining homologous pages trigger the storage event as soon as they are registered. It's just like one tab is watching others' change. If you want single tab watch itself, you could code like this:

```
 var orignalremoveItem = localStorage.removeItem;
    localStorage.removeItem = function(key,newValue){
        var removeItemEvent = new Event("removeItemEvent");
        removeItemEvent.key = key;
        window.dispatchEvent(removeItemEvent);
        orignalremoveItem.apply(this,arguments);
    };
    window.addEventListener("removeItemEvent", function (e) {
        if(localStorage.getItem("token")){
            if(e.key=='token'){
                alert("token，delete success");
            }
        }else{
            alert("no token")
        }
    });
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
```

step 1:
 [image]

step 2:
[image]

step3:
[image]

step4:
[image]